# How can I find the mechanical energy at a given point when there is dissipation of energy during fall?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, physics, classical-mechanics

The problem is as follows:

> A sphere of $2\,kg$ is released (assume $g=10\frac{m}{s^2}$) from a
>   height of $2\,m$ with respect of a horizontal surface. If due air
>   resistance $10\,J$ are dissipated by each meter that the sphere goes
>   down. Find the mechanical energy with respect to the ground (in
>   Joules) on the instant when the kinetic energy is equal to $0.5$ times
>   its potential energy.

The alternatives given are as follows:

$\begin{array}{ll}
1.&350\,J\\
2.&300\,J\\
3.&250\,J\\
4.&200\,J\\
\end{array}$

I'm confused exactly how to tackle this problem.

Essentially what I believe is that:

$E_{k}=\frac{1}{2}E_{u}$

But the thing here that comes into play is that there's energy dissipated when the sphere is falling.

Then the mechanical energy would be as follows:

$E_{u}=E_{k}+E_{u'}$

At that given height there would be kinetic energy and potential energy.

But it mentions that the kinetic energy will be at that given height $\frac{1}{2}E_{u}$

$E_{u}-150=\frac{1}{2}E_{u}+E_{u'}$

$mg(2)-150=\frac{1}{2}(mg(2-x))+mg(2-x)$

By inserting the given values for the mass and gravity this is reduced to:

$x=\frac{17}{3}$

But that's where I became stuck. Can someone help me with this problem?.

Comment: What is $E_{u'}$? Where did the number $150$ come from?

Comment: @DavidK Sorry for that. It was part of my attempt into solving the problem. In the rush I thought that the energy dissipated was $150\,J$ but it was $10\,J$. But overall it isn't right.

Comment: but .. the starting potential energy $mgh= 2\cdot 10 \cdot 2 = 40 J$, isn't it ?

Comment: all options are incorrect object would never have more energy than it had  at the start (40 J in the form of gravitational potential. energy)

Answer (score 1):

Here we are dealing with kinetic energy $E_k$, potential energy $E_u$, and energy transfered to the air by the effect of "air resistance"--let's call this $E_f$. We might be tempted to express each of these as a function of time,
but since the sphere passes through each height at a unique time we can alternatively express each kind of energy as a function of height $x$, where $x=2$ at the point of release.

Energy is preserved so, the sum is constant:

$$ E_k(x_1) + E_u(x_1) + E_f(x_1) = E_k(x_2) + E_u(x_2) + E_f(x_2) $$

where $x_1$ and $x_2$ are any two heights.
Try setting $x_1 = 2$ and let $x_2=h$ be the height at the instant when the kinetic energy is equal to $0.5$ times its potential energy, as asked.

$$ E_k(2) + E_u(2) + E_f(2) = E_k(h) + E_u(h) + E_f(h). \tag1$$

Make formulas for as many of these as you can,
either numbers or functions of $h.$

You should be able to get $E_k(2)$, $E_u(2)$, $E_f(2)$, $E_u(h)$, and $E_f(h)$
directly from the problem statement,
and you can express $E_k(h)$ in terms of $E_u(h)$ based on the "$0.5$ times" condition,
so now you have $E_k(h)$ as a function of $h.$

Plug everything you have into Equation $(1)$ and you'll have an equation with just one unknown, $h.$ Solve it.

Now you know $h$ so you can compute the answer,

$$ E_k(h) + E_u(h). $$

---

An alternative approach: 
In the absence of air resistance, kinetic energy would increase by $20$ J for each meter the sphere descends. But we lose $10$ J to air resistance for each meter.
Since $20 - 10 = 10,$ the kinetic energy increases at a rate of only $10$ J per meter.

On the other hand, potential energy, which starts at $40$ J, still decreases at the rate of $20$ J per meter. That is, the loss of potential energy is twice the gain of kinetic energy (since $20/10 = 2$):

$$ E_u = 40 - 2 E_k.$$

Knowing that $E_k = \frac12 E_u$ at the instant the problem wants you to find the energy, find $E_u$ at that instant, find $E_k$, and add them.

Comment: Why should I account for $E_f(2)$ as if there's air resistance at very instant when the ball is released if there isn't any motion?. If so $E_f(2)=10$?

Comment: $E_f(2)$ is not a quantity of force, it's a quantity of energy. Specifically, it's the amount of mechanical energy that has been lost by the sphere since it was released. At the instant that the sphere is released, at $x=2$, how much mechanical energy has the sphere lost since the time it was released? That should tell you what value to assign to $E_f(2).$

Comment: By looking on the answers sheet it says that the answer to this problem is $300\,J$ this doesn't make any sense to me. But I can understand that right at the beginning there is no motion, no friction acting on the ball, just potential energy. Therefore $E_{k}=E_f(2)=0$ are we right on this?. Using the whole condition thing I'm arriving at $h=1\,m$. The thing is the ***interpretation*** of mechanical energy.

Comment: In this case I believe they're asking for the contribution of the kinetic energy and the potential energy alone (without the frictional part) which it would be $30\,J$. Because it it would be only potential energy that would make $20\,J$ and if they would be asking for all energy it would be $40\,J$ as it is preserved all the way down and there wouldn't be any bother to do any rest of calculations other than finding the potential energy at the top. Am I right with this logic?. Can you ***explain*** if I am good with this to me please?.

Comment: Based on the numbers you have, I also get 30 J at a height of 1 m as the solution. Your book seems to have an issue with the placement of the decimal point, the answers are all off by a factor of 10. If we started at 20 meters height then the answer would be 300, so maybe they dropped a digit from the height.

Answer (score 0):

Attempt:

Let $y=0$ at the ground, $y=h=2$ at point of release.

After $(h-y)$ meters fall  $E_{diss} =-10(h-y)$ energy lost.

$E_{pot}(h)=mgh$;

$E_{pot}(h)= mgh=$

$(1/2)E_{pot}(y) +E_{pot}(y) +10(h-y);$

$E_{pot}(h)=2(10)2=$

$(3/2)2(10)y+10(2-y);$

$40=30y+20-10y$;

$20y=20$; $y=1$.

$E_{pot}(y=1)=2(10)(1)=20$.

Note:

0) Without dissipation

Energy conservation:

At any point $y$ above ground we have

$E_{kin}(y)+E_{pot}(y)=E_{pot}(h)=mgh;$

1) With dissipation:

Energy lost falling a distance $(h-y)$:

$E_{diss}(y)=-10(h-y)$;

The remaining energy is split :

$E_{kin}(y)+E_{pot}(y)=$

$E_{pot}(h)-10(h-y)$;

Additional info: For some $y$ we have

$E_{kin}(y)=(1/2)E_{pot}(y)$.

Comment: Apparently there isn't a match within the alternatives given. Can you explain the reasoning behind the equation which you have used?. I know it is the conservation of mechanical energy but if energy is dissipated why is it $+10(h-y)$? and ***not*** $-10(h-y)$?.

Comment: I try.Start with the given energy. E=mgh, at h above the ground. At some height y (>0) above the ground you have E_pot =mgy ;  E_kin=(1/2)mgy (given) now add energy that has been lost : 10(h-y)(here positive),   to mgy +(1/2)mgy +10(h-y)= mgh to recover, equate to the original energy. Yes, dissipated energy is lost. Hence E_kin is smaller, adding the "lost part" gives you the energy balance at t=0.Your thoughts?

Comment: I'm confused exactly on why the answer should be $ 20\,J$ and not $40\,J$ ***haven't*** we established that the mechanical energy (which is what they're asking at that point be the same at what it was just at the beginning when the ball was released?. I mean accounting for the dissipation due air resistance. In this case you're only calculating the potential energy for that given height. Why? shouldn't account also for the kinetic energy?.

Comment: Can you ***please*** explain this part?. Or is it that what they are asking is the energy ***without*** the disspation which it would be  $30\,J$?. The answers sheet says that the answer is $300\,J$ but this doesn't make any sense, I suspect that there's an added zero by error. But if judging from this perspective I believe that the answer would  be $30\,J$.

Comment: Chris.Start with potential energy mgh (h=2).If there is no dissipation E(kin)(y), kinetic energy at y above ground, + E(pot)(y). above ground =mgh .Correct? The sum of them equals the original E(pot)(h). Now energy is lost -10(h-y), y location above ground (h=2, and 0\le y\le 2. At any point y above ground we have left  E(pot)(h)-10m(2-y) to be "shared between E(kin)(y) and E(pot)(y).  I edit , give me a few moments.

Comment: Chris.Try to go through. Of course I can be wrong. Let me know.

Answer (score 0):

we know ,by **work-energy theoram**

$(U_{f}-U_{i})+(K_{f}-K_{i})=\Delta U +\Delta K=W_{nc}=\Delta E  $

where $E$ is total mechanical(kinetic $K$ + potential $U$) energy at any instant & $Wnc$ is work done by non conservative forces,air drag ,at same instant. 
chose ground as reference for potential energy (that is $U_{f}=0$) where subscript $f$ means final position

apply WETheo. between top point and ground to get final kinetic energy of sphere when it hits ground

$(0-20\times2)+(K_{f}-0)=-10\times2\implies K_{f}=20 J$

again apply WE theo. bewteen any intermediate point and ground (consider ground as final position and intermediate point as initial)

$[0-20(2-y)]+\left[20-0.5 (20(2-y))\right]=-10(2-y)\implies y=1$

so, total mechanical energy at this instant

$20(2-1) + 0.5(20\times (2-1))=30J$